# Why is git deleting files?

Tags: git

I am not sure if it could be a reason, but foreword. I had a problem  I can't pull from a remote repo in order to solve this issue, I created new repo in a new folder `git init` and set `git remote` after this I pull from the origin.

About the current issue: other devs have merged changes into the master branch and now I need to pull it to my dev branch. After the merge, I found out that I get all new files after a pull from the master branch, but also I see that merge remove all the new files that I created locally...

I think about a possible reason that after I created the new repo and set `get remote` I did not get a history and I don't know why, but maybe it is a reason.

What am I doing wrong? How to solve it?

**EDIT**

I am using `GitExentions` as UI.

After the merge with the master, there were a few conflicts that I solved.

**EDIT2**
According to the suggestion of @RJFalconer in comments it is better to concentrate on solving a problem with `git clone` from the origin repo, but anyway I have already made a lot of changes that is not in the remote repo. So, even if I will fix `get clone` issue, I need somehow to move my changes from the current repo.

Comment: The short answer is that "it does not delete files". Unless you're explicitly doing `reset --hard` then git is not what is deleting untracked files in your local checkout. 
Can you explain what you mean by 'new files'? Have they been previously staged/committed?

Comment: `other devs pull changes in the master branch` -> Do you mean `other devs have merged changes into master branch`?

Comment: @RJFalconer yes it is

Comment: @RJFalconer edited

Comment: @RJFalconer but weird that files have already was committed, and they exist only on my local branch, but after the merge with the master I see that they were deleted...

Comment: Were there conflicts when you merged? Can you be more specific about what commands you ran? Are you using a git UI (fork, visual studio plugin, etc)?

Comment: Well I had an answer mid-draft but I was too slow. Jesus Christ guys. 
Aleksey in short you probably want to use `git clone` to get the first repo (not `git init` then `git remote add`). 
You can still recover your files if they have been committed.

Comment: @RJFalconer edited quesiton

Comment: @RJFalconer But it was a problem that I can't execute `git clone`, because repo size is big enough like 8 Gb, and I tried a few times and every time on 78% I got some errors. So, I decided to make `git init` and `git remote` and take only that branches that I needed. I did not lose my file because I make `git merge --abort`, and still trying to make git merge. Do you have an idea, why git removes files and how to prevent it?

Comment: I suspect your local master isn't in the same tree as the remote master. Try `git checkout master; git rebase origin/master`. The real problem to fix is your big repo and the errors you get when you try to clone it. I'd probably focus on that.

Comment: @RJFalconer would you mean that I need to checkout to local master then `git rebase` with remote one and then merge with my dev branch?

Comment: @RJFalconer edited quesiton

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that "it does not delete files". Unless you're explicitly doing `reset --hard` or `clean -f` then git won't delete untracked files in your local checkout

> I created new repo in a new folder `git init` and set `git remote`

Sounds like you've made a new repo and added a remote for the first repo.
I think what you really wanted to do was `git clone` the first repo instead.

> all the new files that I created locally

It's unclear what you mean by this, but it sounds like perhaps you added some files to your repo (the empty one created with `git init`), possibly committing them. Let's assume you committed them, as if you did not and they're not on disk now they're lost anyway.

### My theory

You probably have 2 trees in your repo; the files you added, and the remote master from the remote. You checked out the remote, and your files disappeared.

If you rebase your original tree onto the remote, then your files should be back. You could also do a baseless merge (baseless as there's no common parent).

Find out your remote name:
`git remote -v`
Should return something like:
`your-remote-name https://my-url/something`

Then rebase:
`git rebase --onto master --root your-remote-name/master`

If that does not work go read about `git reflog` to go back through your recent commits to find the one that contains the files you added. (Assuming you no-longer have copies of the files you wanted to add)